# JNI_CreateJavaVM: "Could not reserve enough space for code cache" on OpenBSD

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, openbsd

I try to invoke Java code from C using OpenJDK 1.8 on OpenBSD 6.1 virtual machine

There is my test program source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    JavaVMInitArgs args;

    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    args.options = options;
    args.nOptions = 1;

    if ( JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &env, (void *) &args))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create the JVM\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/jdk-1.8.0/include -I/usr/local/jdk-1.8.0/include/openbsd -L/usr/local/jdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm main.c
```

run:

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/jdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/server/ ./a.out
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for code cache
```

I tried to add `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m` option, but the result is always the same

When I run the test code on Linux, everything works fine

Comment: What does ulimit say your process memory limits are?

Comment: There is `ulimit -a` output: data seg size (kbytes, -d) 33554432, max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 671061, max memory size (kbytes, -m) 2011444, stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192, virtual memory  (kbytes, -v) 33562624